# How do I add html files to my godaddy domain without using website bulider?

Tags: html, cpanel

I currently have a trial on my GoDaddy account. I created a tester domain and I'm trying to make my website entirely out of HTML (not with GoDaddy website builder). For some reason, it's only letting me add HTML code in certain places on website builder. How do I add HTML files using cpanel to my domain?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are only trying to use html files, use any free shared website hosting service provider online (Some googling would work). Sign Up, login to the cpanel you will be prompted by the hosting service provider either by E-Mail or on the dashboard when you login the nameservers which are something like 'ns1.hostingprovider.com'.Login to your godaddy dashboard open your domain settings and update the nameservers with the ones your hosting provider gives you.Log on back to your hosting cpanel navigate to add files(html,css, a Readme file is optional) to your domain and wait  Boom, and your files can go live within an hour of updating the nameservers on godaddy but sometimes this might take 24-48 hours.

Note -  This process is only to know the general process to host files, if you consider hosting larger applications built in Multiple stacks and environments please check other threads when trying to deploy the application.